# Integrating OpenCMS with Liferay

Tags: content-management-system, liferay-6, opencms

I am using Liferay 6.1. I want to use OpenCMS with Liferay. How can I do it ? I have googled this topic. But could not find any solution.
Can anyone help me ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'integrating' exactly? And why would you want to do this? Basically, you have two servlets, you would merge them into one web.xml - pure technically. But I don't see yet the purpose of integrating OpenCms with Liferay. Do you want to use OpenCms as a content delivery platform for Liferay? Which Liferay do you mean? Social Office, or the Portal? Doesn't Liferay already provide basic editing functionality?

Comment: @ Mathias I want to use OpenCms as the content management system for Liferay portal instead of Liferay's CMS.

Comment: I see. Not sure if there are detailed instructions on the web. I think common would be to let OpenCms provide the content via web service. There was a ppt of 2009 on that topic, I guess you've found that already as well, but it doesn't go into technical details. http://www.opencms.org/export/sites/opencms/en/events/opencms_days_2009/slides/t3.pdf (Dan Liliendahl, he's also the author of one of the OpenCms books).

Answer (score 0):

Integrating OpenCms with Liferay Portal Server
there are many options, some

1. OC & LR integrated in the same container
   pro: cost (if tou pay per container)
   cons: maintenance, high impact on installation
2. OC/LR on different containers comunicating via http
   pro: easier then 1
   cons: low level comunication capabilities
3. OC/LR on different containers, OC expose WebServices called by LR
   pro: loose coupling, poor installaction impacts
   cons: bit of it skills

This is a big problem, you cannot do it all by your self.
There should by a community to support 3rd solution

[wtach this link...](http://www.opencms.org/en/events/opencms_days_2009/program/sessions/t3.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility could be CMIS (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services). Newer versions of OpenCms can act as a CMIS Server and Liferay is able to act as a CMIS client.

This would be a standard-based integration. This means, there should be some documentation how to do certain things.